# Обработка изображения с камеры для предпросмотра

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток!
Если кто-нибудь работал с камерой на android подскажите, каким образом можно изменить изображение, которое выводится в превью. В интернете нахожу только примеры с конвертацией, а хотелось бы вывести на экран, например, квадратик в определенном месте.
Как я понял все изменения нужно проводить в методе

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
```

где в data приходит изображение, но в каком оно виде и как его изменить?
Спасибо, за понимание

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В StackOverflow тема подробно обсуждалась. И был выложен рекомендованный способ обработки изображения. В общем сошлись на том, что raw изображение подается в виде YUV, которое надо перекодировать, чтобы из него получить `Bitmap`. Ну а коли уж есть `Bitmap` - дальше можно как угодно его крутить, рисовать квадратики и проч.

Фтыкать [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893072/getting-frames-from-video-image-in-android).